# Open m.localhost:8080/ url deployed locally on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, mobile-website

I got a weird thing going on, I can't open mobile version of the url on the localhost (i.e. locally deployed webapp in tomcat). While the same is working fine for our QA environment. Which I don't have access to. I can only access  the QA environment. Is there any particular configuration required for this inside tomcat

Comment: Are you sure about m.localhost? Localhost is just host name, like using ip 127.0.0.1.
If you have a different from desktop mobile version app, what's servlet name of it?

Comment: I am not sure about m.localhost, I am trying to access the mobile version of the website but it isn't accessible, I am not sure why. The problem is I can't even compare the QA environment configuration to see whats the difference. I am not sure about the servlet name, let me just check for it.

Comment: Is the mobile version is another app? Or you just try to open it from mobile and it's the same app?

Comment: It seem to be same app, but have different pages for mobile as view part

Comment: If it's the same app, it's working on the same servlet. So you should open from mobile on the same address what you opened desktop version. If there's different pages, you should open just these pages, not m.localhost. It would be like http://localhost:8080 /{servlet name}/{path to your page}

Comment: ok, cool .. what if it is a different app then localhost:8080/thatDifferentAppName would be the url?

Comment: yes. try to find out your web apps tructure in {tomcat folder} / webapps. There would be your deployed servlets.

Comment: Further more the QA link works fine with emulator, but I can't make the local link work on emulator, I guess this is the chrome emulator problem, Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I found it a bit strange that the m.localhost:8080 wasn't working on firefox, I installed chrome just to check this and it was working fine on chrome, I could see the mobile version of my website ;) Posting this for others info ... :) :)

Comment: @BilboBaggins possibly the user-agent in firefox wasn't set correctly if you confirm, that the Chrome Mobile Emulator worked for you.

Comment: @DanielK ya I think so, however I could see the site in chrome(mobile version) without emulator. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Localhost is exactly that - local host. So unless you're running Tomcat on your phone, you will not be able to access the web application via http://localhost:8080/your-app.

What I do to test mobile applications on Tomcat is the following:

1. Make sure port 8080 is open in the firewall (at least to the local network)
2. Start up Tomcat and deploy the application
3. Connect my phone to my local WiFi network
4. Browse to http://ip-address:8080/my-app

One of these days I'll set up my router to do internal DNS. For now, the IP address is sufficient.

Please note that if you use virtual hosts (named virtual hosts in Apache HTTPD), you will have to deploy your web application to the default host or set an Alias with the value of the IP address of the machine that Tomcat is running on.

I also run an Apache HTTPD server with mod_jk. This allows my to access the Tomcat application via http://ip-address/my-app.

I do this all the time on both Linux and Windows. I don't have a Macintosh, but only the particulars (setup) would change.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, what I asked for is about accessing the mobile version of site on local machine, with tomcat on firefox